# ошибка lateinit property drillerAdapter has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin

Господа кто подскажет у меня у адаптера такой конструктор:

```
    JavaDrillerAdapter(@NonNull DiffUtil.ItemCallback diffCallback, Boolean nativToForeign) {
            super(diffCallback);
            this.nativToForeign = nativToForeign;
        }
```

Почему мне студио дает ошибку lateinit property drillerAdapter has not been initialized?
вот че в фрагменте:

```
    @AndroidEntryPoint
    class DrillerFragment : Fragment(R.layout.cardstack_layout), CardStackListener {

        private val viewModel: DrillerViewModel by viewModels()
        private lateinit var drillerAdapter: JavaDrillerAdapter

        override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

            viewModel.readTransDir.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
                drillerAdapter = JavaDrillerAdapter(JavaDrillerAdapter.JavaDrillerDiff(), it)
            }

        
        val binding = CardstackLayoutBinding.bind(view)

        viewModel.getLivedataList().observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            drillerAdapter.submitList(it)
            Log.d(TAG, "drlr workWorkList.size = " + it.size)
        }

        val drillerLayoutManager = CardStackLayoutManager(requireContext(), this)
        
    drillerLayoutManager.setSwipeableMethod(SwipeableMethod.AutomaticAndManual)
        binding.apply {
            cardStackView.apply {
                adapter = drillerAdapter // ВОТ НА ЭТУ СТРОКУ ССЫЛАЮТСЯ ЛОГИ С ОШИБКОЙ
                layoutManager = drillerLayoutManager
                setHasFixedSize(true)
            }
        }
        viewModel.get4words()
    }


    override fun onCardSwiped(direction: Direction?) {
        if (direction == Direction.Bottom) {
            currentWord.shown = false
            viewModel.update(currentWord)
        }
        viewModel.removeAndAddWord(currentWord)
        Log.d(TAG, currentWord.foreign + " is removed. (drlr)")
    }

    override fun onCardAppeared(view: View?, position: Int) {
        currentWord = drillerAdapter.getWordAt(position)
        Log.d(TAG,  "onCardAppeared: " + currentWord.foreign + " IS NOW currentWord, position in adapter - " + position + " (drlr)"
        )
    }

    override fun onCardDisappeared(view: View?, position: Int) {
        currentWord = drillerAdapter.getWordAt(position)
        Log.d(TAG, "onCardDisappeared: " + currentWord.foreign + " IS NOW currentWord, position in adapter - " + position + " (drlr)"
        )
    }
```

Как тогда код переделать?

Comment: Судя по ошибке, у вас где-то идёт обращение к drillerAdapter переменной до инициализации оной. Судя по всему в том коде, который вы не показали.

Comment: получается что так. Но не пойму тогда как лучше написать, потому что мне нужно воткнуть в конструктор адаптера ливдату, и декларирован адаптер должен быть за пределами onViewCreated, так как на него ссылаются потом методы снизу кода. (я добавил код недостававший)

Comment: У вас как-то совсем логика перепуталась. Попробуйте создавать адаптер при его объявлении. Задайте ваше Boolean значение по умолчанию и/или не отображайте список данных, пока это значение не вытащите откудато. Вот когда вы его получите - можете передать в адаптер, не через конструктор, а через сеттер и тогда отображать список или менять его.

Comment: ... спасибо, win